# Converter e salvar hora no banco com PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um campo input em que o usuário digita uma hora (ex: "08:00") converto essa string com o strtotime() e converto novamente com date() e salvo no mysql no formato TIME. Até ai está tudo certo, apesar de achar que deve ter uma forma melhor de fazer isso. O problema é que se o campo input estiver vazio ele salva no banco "00:00:00" sendo que não deveria salvar nada. Se fizer um if (if($sfi1)) para saber se o strtotime retorna false e usar o date() somente se existir algo, tudo funciona corretamente. Mas quero saber se tem uma forma melhor do que usar if em cada input.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $this->modality = new Modality($input);

    $sfi1 = strtotime($request->input('segunda-feira-inicio1'));
    if($sfi1) {
        $this->modality->segunda_feira_inicio1 = date("H:i:s", $sfi1);
    }
    $sff1 = strtotime($request->input('segunda-feira-fim1'));
    $this->modality->segunda_feira_fim1 = date("H:i:s", $sff1);

    $this->modality->save();
    return redirect()->action('ModalityController@index');
}
```

Formulário:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Modalidades</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Modalidade" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Descrição</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Descrição" name="description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload de imagens</label>
                <input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple >
                <p class="help-block">Para selecionar multiplas imagens segure Crtl e escolha as imagens</p>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">Horários</label>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dia da Semana</th>
                        <th>Início 1</th>
                        <th>Fim 1</th>
                        <th>Início 2</th>
                        <th>Fim 2</th>
                        <th>Início 3</th>
                        <th>Fim 3</th>
                        <th>Início 4</th>
                        <th>Fim 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Segunda-feira</td>         
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-inicio1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-fim1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-inicio2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-fim2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-inicio3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-fim3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-inicio4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="segunda-feira-fim4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Terça-feira</td>         
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-inicio1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-fim1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-inicio2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-fim2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-inicio3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-fim3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-inicio4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="terca-feira-fim4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Quarta-feira</td>         
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-inicio1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-fim1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-inicio2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-fim2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-inicio3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-fim3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-inicio4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quarta-feira-fim4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Quinta-feira</td>         
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-inicio1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-fim1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-inicio2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-fim2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-inicio3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-fim3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-inicio4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="quinta-feira-fim4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sexta-feira</td>         
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-inicio1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-fim1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-inicio2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-fim2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-inicio3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-fim3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-inicio4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sexta-feira-fim4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sábado</td>         
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-inicio1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-fim1">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-inicio2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-fim2">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-inicio3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-fim3">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-inicio4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="sabado-fim4">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar modalidade</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se o usuário não informar os dados, no banco de dados ficará `NULL`?

Comment: O que você pode fazer é criar um laço de repetição que faça a verificação em todos os valores, mas para isso precisaria saber exatamente como é o seu formulário HTML.

Comment: E qual é o padrão dos nomes? Só altera o valor no final? E existe algum outro campo além desses no formulário?

Comment: Sim, já falei que há, mas como eu disse, é necessário saber como está o formulário. Não estou dizendo que ele está errado, mas é necessário saber qual é o nome dos campos. Sem o nome, como saberei quais os campos que devo verificar? Basta dizer se os nomes seguem um padrão ou não ou se há outros campos além destes no formulário. **Sem essas informações não tem como te responder**. Então se quiser ajuda, por favor, ajude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com Laravel é possível obter a lista de todos os valores passados na requisição, com exceção de alguns, através do método:

```
$request->except([...]);
```

Então, primeiro começamos armazenando essa lista em uma variável:

```
$fields = $request->except(["_token", "name", "description", "photo"]);
```

Para percorrer todos os valores, basta utilizar um laço de repetição:

```
foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

Se o valor do campo estiver vazio, atualiza a coluna para `NULL`:

```
foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
    if(empty($value)) {
        $value = NULL;
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Convertemos o horário para o formato desejado:

```
foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
    if(empty($value)) {
        $value = NULL;
    } else {
        $column = str_replace('-', '_', $field);
        $value = date("H:i:s", strtotime($value));
    }
}
```

Os nomes dos campos estão no formato `segunda-feira-inicio1`, mas os nomes das colunas estão no formato `segunda_feira_inicio1`, ou seja, para obter o respectivo nome da coluna a partir do nome do campo basta substituir `-` por `_`:

```
foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
    if(empty($value)) {
        $value = NULL;
    } else {
        $column = str_replace('-', '_', $field);
        $value = date("H:i:s", strtotime($value));
    }

    $column = str_replace('-', '_', $field);
}
```

E então atribuímos o valor à coluna:

```
foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
    if(empty($value)) {
        $value = NULL;
    } else {
        $column = str_replace('-', '_', $field);
        $value = date("H:i:s", strtotime($value));
    }

    $column = str_replace('-', '_', $field);
    $this->modality->{$column} = $value;
}
```

Assim, seu método completo deve ficar parecido com:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $this->modality = new Modality($input);

    $fields = $request->except(["_token", "name", "description", "photo"]);

    foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
        if(empty($value)) {
            $value = NULL;
        } else {
            $column = str_replace('-', '_', $field);
            $value = date("H:i:s", strtotime($value));
        }

        $column = str_replace('-', '_', $field);
        $this->modality->{$column} = $value;
    }

    $this->modality->save();
    return redirect()->action('ModalityController@index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar o atributo 'required' do HTML no teu HTML. Assim, o campo será sempre obrigatório.

Algo como:

`<input type="text" name="hora" required>`

Assim, a requisição não será feita para o PHP caso esteja em branco. Você também pode usar máscaras com Javascript + HTML para validar o formato da hora inserida, para impedir que o usuário insira algo por escrito ou algo assim.

Para validar os inputs, você pode pegar o $input que você recebeu e percorrer eles validando se o valor é igual a '' (em branco), se for, você seta null caso seja um input do tipo 'time', com isso, se o valor for null, ele ficará salvo como sem valor no banco. Pra converter pra array o input tem o método [toArray()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_toArray)

Comment: Entendi. Você pode pegar o teu input e percorrer todos eles com um for, se o valor dele for igual a '' (em branco), tu pode setar o valor para null, assim quando salvar no banco ele não vai salvar como 00:00:00